# Timers and multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a question about timers and threads. I noticed that the timers misbehaving when started within the threads, while the timers are part of the Winform.

Generally I'm interested in problems related threads and timers.

Happy New Year to you all, the answers may be to wait until 2011:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using a `System.Threading.Timer` and using a `TimerCallback` that performs GUI updates. Is that it?

There are a number of correct ways to deal with this. Use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and handle its `Tick` event if you're looking to update the UI. Use a `BackgroundWorker`, do non-UI work in its `DoWork` event and then perform UI updates in its `RunWorkerCompleted` event if you're performing long-running background tasks.

In general, the important thing to understand about multithreading as it pertains to Windows Forms is this: all Windows Forms application have a UI thread, which is the *only* thread that is allowed to perform UI updates. It is continually processing a queue onto which user actions are pushed and handle via events. When you try to do anything that updates a UI control from any thread besides this thread, you get an exception because this behavior was not planned for in the design of Windows Forms components, and would therefore very likely cause bugs or possibly crash the entire application.

So the approach to multithreading is generally to separate work into two parts, that which can be done in the background (on a non-UI thread) and that which must sent to the queue being processed by the UI thread so that it can be handled in a safe manner. The usefulness of types like `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and `BackgroundWorker` is that they encapsulate many of the difficult details of this process for you, allowing you to focus on the code you want to run.

That's a high level view of how multithreading works with Windows Forms. I'm sure others can provide plenty of references pointing you to more information on the subject (and if nobody else does, maybe I can look some up later).

Comment: I am using System.Windows.Forms.Timer to update the UI. When I click button, thread is starting, and then from that thread I am starting two timers one is ticking every second and another has long tick event. Sometimes it is working correct, sometime there is some errors.

Comment: When I start program, timer2 is ticking on winform startup which is strange because I didn't start timer yet in code. Maybe it is because Timer Enabled properties which I set as true (Enabled generations of Elapsed events).

Comment: Question is how to start timers which belong to Winform thread, from another thread.

Comment: I did it. I use backgroundworker, and programmatically use 
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer2.Enabled = true;

Answer (score 1):

[Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) is a good article to read.

Answer (score 0):

Google maybe?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx